# Database query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, database-schema

so I'm trying to query a database and grab user names in the "name column" and image paths from the "image_path" column, but I'm not quite sure how to write a database query in Ruby on Rails. Here is my code so far. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
# load rails
require '../../config/boot.rb' 
require '../../config/application.rb'
require 'sqlite3'
Rails.application.require_environment!

db = SQLite3::Database.new( "standalone.moose" )
db.execute( "select * from standalone.moose" ) do |row|   
end
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using Rails but not using ActiveRecord or another ORM? Doing raw queries like this is extremely irregular. `Moose.connection` for model `Moose` would provide a number of generic helper methods like `select_all` for low-level data calls.

Answer (score 0):

standalone.moose is the name of your database I'm guessing. You write queries against the db but your queries would query tables in the db so something like

```
"select * from users"
```